# Deselect current list view item if selected again

Tags: java, android

I currently have a list view in which you can select an item and it will highlight the currently selected item. But I would like to set it sot that so that if the user clicks on the same item currently selected in the list again it will unhighlight the list item and have no list item currently selected/

```
currentUsersCameras.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {


    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(3, 169, 244));
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Add a boolean status for your `Item` class

Comment: Try this `view.setBackgroundColor(isSelected(position) ? Color.rgb(3, 169, 244) : Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: What I do is. When clicked i add the listitem to a set. If added to set I change the color. Now when i click that item again, I check if its there in the set. If it is present in the set i change the color back to normal. I need to delete multiple selected items, So I maintain the set but your requirement can be different.

Answer (score 0):

Listview/Recyclerview items requires you to handle **if** and **else** cases always. So if you want to do something for one item and not for another item, and similarly if you want to do and undo the same thing to the same item, handle both IF and ELSE